# Setup hibernate using spring: hibernate.connection.autocommit has no effect

Tags: spring, hibernate

I try to set autocommit to false for hibernate.

I tried setting provider_disables_autocommit = true, I also tried setting hibernate.connection.autocommit = false. But neither works.

I use spring to set up hibernate. My xml file is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory_1">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.hibernate.mapping</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
SessionFactory factory = (SessionFactory)context.getBean("sessionFactory_1");
session = factory.openSession();
session.save(...);
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Why should it work. You are injecting a datasource which is managing the connections not hibernate. So basically all `hibernate.connection` settings are useless.

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you!

Comment: @M.Deinum do you know how to use LocalSessionFactoryBean without passing in a datasource?

Comment: Nevermind, I figure it out.

Comment: Well, seems like they haven't implemented it yet, so it's not possible if I want to set up hibernate through spring (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9261)

Comment: You can use the properties and simply not pass in a `DataSource` but that is something even the Hibernate team generally advices against. So you are better off injecting a `DataSource` so you can fully configure your connection pool. Setting auto-commit to `false` can be easily done on the datasource.